# How to include Qt header to kernel?

Tags: c++, qt, opencl

I'd like something like:

```
#include <QImage>

void __kernel dither(__global int* image, __global int* result)
{
    int red = qRed(image[get_global_id(0)]);
    //...
}
```

But I get a runtime error:

> Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

How do I solve it?

Host:

```
std::ifstream sourceFile("OrderedDitheringKernel.cl");

std::string kernelCode(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile),(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(kernelCode);

sources.push_back({kernelCode.c_str(), kernelCode.length()});

cl::Program program(context, sources);

if (program.build({defaultDevice}) != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cerr << "Error while building kernel: " <<
                 program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(defaultDevice) << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
else
    qDebug() << "Kernel compiled succesfully\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include C or C++ headers into OpenCL C code as well as link against static or shared C/C++ libraries.

OpenCL C is a subset of C language, that doesn't support linking in common meaning. So, only OpenCL C source files can be included by '#include' preprocessor directive or compiled together into one binary at program building stage.